# Check C++ concepts on purely virtual class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-templates

I am beginning to use C++ concepts to document requirements on simple template methods (used to convert vector of stuff to string). It works as expected, until mixed with purely virtual interface.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Content, typename ToString>
concept IsStringConverter = requires(Content c, ToString p) // make sure I can write std::string s = p(c);
{
    { p.operator()(c) } -> std::convertible_to<std::string>;
};

template<typename Content, typename ToString>
// requires IsStringConverter<Content, ToString> // WORKS OK AS LONG AS COMMENTED
std::string toString(const std::vector<Content> &container, const ToString &printer) {
    std::string result;
    for(const auto &elem:container) result+=printer(elem)+" ";
    return result;
}

class StringPrinterInterface {
public:
    virtual ~StringPrinterInterface() = default;
    virtual std::string operator()(const std::string &input) const = 0;
};

class StringPrinterImpl : public StringPrinterInterface {
public:
    virtual std::string operator()(const std::string &input) const {return input;};
};

int main() {
    auto stringVector = std::vector<std::string>{"alpha", "beta", "gamma"};
    auto stringPrinterF     = [](const std::string &str) {return str;};
    auto stringSizePrinterF = [](const std::string &str) {return std::to_string(str.size());};

    std::cout << toString(stringVector, stringPrinterF)     << std::endl;
    std::cout << toString(stringVector, stringSizePrinterF) << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<StringPrinterImpl> sizePrinter = std::make_unique<StringPrinterImpl>();
    std::cout << toString(stringVector, *sizePrinter) << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<StringPrinterInterface> sizePrinter2 = std::make_unique<StringPrinterImpl>();
    std::cout << toString(stringVector, *sizePrinter2) << std::endl; // FAILS TO COMPILE if `requires` is not commented!

   // my workaround
   auto wrapper = [&sizePrinter2](const std::string &str) {return sizePrinter2->operator()(str);};
    std::cout << toString(stringVector, wrapper) << std::endl; 
}
```

So I have this `toString` method that iterates on vector elements, and calls `ToString.operator()` on each element.

`ToString` is a template parameter; it can be a lambda or a class instance. **I added a concept to make sure the `operator()` is there.**

However, when passing a virtual class (that have a virtual pure `operator()`), I got the following message:

```
error: invalid abstract parameter type
...
note:   because the following virtual functions are pure
```

There error message is clear. My questions are:

1. why the concept mecanism can't be applied to interfaces? I mean, the method is pure but I am passing an instantiated object so the method is implemented.
2. Is there a workaround so that I can pass lambda OR virtual pure interface? Or I am doing something fondamentally wrong?
3. I managed to do what I wanted by wrapping the interface in a lambda, is this a valid workaround?

Comment: Aside: you can have the simpler: `concept IsStringConverter = std::is_invocable_r_v<std::string, ToString, Content>`

Answer (score 4):

The concept mechanism can be applied to interfaces. But see how you have

```cpp
concept IsStringConverter = requires(Content c, ToString p)
{
  // ...
}
```

That means that all the requirements in `IsStringConverter` require `Content` and `ToString` to be able to hand you an object *by value*. When `ToString` is an abstract class like `StringPrinterInterface`, you cannot do this, because you cannot have an instance of that class.

But hey, notice that your `toString` function doesn't actually require you to take a `ToString` object by value. You can update your concept to reflect this intended usage:

```cpp
concept IsStringConverter = requires(const Content& c, const ToString& p)
{
  { p(c) } -> std::convertible_to<std::string>;
}
```

I've also changed it so that it takes `Content` by const reference and changed `p.operator()(c)` to `p(c)`. In both cases, this makes the concept more accurately reflect the actual intended required uses of the types. For example, a function pointer doesn't have an `operator()`, but can be used in the expression `p(c)`.

Comment: Also probably `const Content& c` instead of `Content c` given that `printer` is called on a `const` lvalue in `toString` and `p(c)` instead of `p.operator()(c)`, since the former syntax is actually used  in `toString`.

Comment: Considered this, but considering the `std::vector<Content>` that's expected, it would actually be misleading to accept an abstract type for `Content`. Perhaps `toString` should take a pair of iterators or an iterator and a sentinel instead of assuming a specific container.

Comment: It is about the `const`. The concept should match the use in the constrained function exactly, otherwise you have edge cases where it doesn't work.